# C# - Form2 value to Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble passing values ​​entered in form2(citacao) to form1(principal).

Principal.cs (form1)

```
richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(citacao.valor_edit[0]);
```

Citacao.cs (form2)

```
public string[] valor_edit = new string[3];
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    valor_edit[0] = memoEdit1.Text;
    valor_edit[1] = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    valor_edit[2] = textEdit1.Text;

}
```

But when I click the button nothing happens , the values ​​are not inserted into the richedit I like it.

I already have this on form (Pass DataGrid to ComboBox)

Form1 (principal)

```
private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    citacao cita = new citacao(this);
    cita.Show();
}
```

form2(citação)

```
public citacao(principal gridForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm1 = gridForm;
}

// LOAD ALL FONTS (Referencias);
private void citacao_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in frm1.DataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: when is this line: `richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(citacao.valor_edit[0]); ` executed? When do the values have to appear in Form1 ?

Comment: is to be run when the form2 close. When try to compile `Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string' C:\Users\RCA\Desktop\ABTN_Format\ABNTFacil\ABNTFacil\principal.cs 93 50 ABNTFacil`, `Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ABNTFacil.citacao.valor_edit' C:\Users\RCA\Desktop\ABTN_Format\ABNTFacil\ABNTFacil\principal.cs 93 50 ABNTFacil`.

I Tried this too, but dont work `citacao cita = new citacao(this);
            richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(cita.valor_edit);`

Comment: could you post more code, it is difficult to jump between the disconnected code and try to figure out the program flow

Comment: so you have the closing event of form 2 in form 1 am I right?

Comment: your error comes from this line `richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(citacao.valor_edit[0]); ` because you use the class name (citacao) so the compiler looks for a static variable with the name `valor_edit` but it is not static

Comment: If you used correct C# naming conventions for classes, then you would have found this bug a lot sooner. Classes should start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let's see whether I understood your situation :)

declare your variable in Form 1 as a class variable

```
private citacao cita;
```

then initialize it in the button press event

```
private void barButtonItem1_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    cita = new citacao(this);
    // subscribe to the closing event
    cita.FormClosing += form_FormClosing;
    cita.Show();
}

// when Form 2 will be closed you can execute your important line in the event
void form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // BUT! you have to use the variable name!
    richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(cita.valor_edit[0]);    
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok after looking at the entire code:
please remove the button3!  and this entire code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cita = new citacao(this);
    richEditControl1.Document.AppendText(citacao.valor_edit); // this line is the problem!
}
```

The function `AppendText` probably needs a `string` as parameter and you give the entire array! 
If you subscribe to the closing event in Form1 / principal and also implement
the event, your data will be transmitted automatically as soon as the Form 2 disappears from the screen :)

Comment: Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ABNTFacil.citacao.valor_edit' C:\Users\RCA\Desktop\ABTN_Format\ABNTFacil\ABNTFacil\principal.cs 105 50 ABNTFacil

Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string' C:\Users\RCA\Desktop\ABTN_Format\ABNTFacil\ABNTFacil\principal.cs 105 50 ABNTFacil


Same error before - Here you can see all the code.... citação.cs (http://pastebin.com/TfTMtaZc), principal.cs (http://pastebin.com/cuQWiRTN)

Comment: @CarlosIyu Pass the parent form to the child form as a parameter in its constructor, or via a property prior to calling `Show()` on the child form and store it in an instance variable.

Comment: @CarlosIyu I edited my answer. Thank you for giving access to the entire code, information makes problem solving much easier :)

Comment: @CarlosIyu glad I could help. Events are really worth to dive more into it. :)